# fread() in R unable to open a file

Tags: r, fread

I am trying to open a file in R as shown below:

```
data0 <- filename_a %>%  map_df(~fread(., sep=",", skip=1))
```

Let us assume that fread fails to read this file for various reasons. Such as the file is under use by other program or the file does not exist. In such a case I would like to read filename_b instead.
At this moment, as soon as the above step fails, the code stops executing. How can I read filename_b when filename_a fails to read?

Comment: If `filename_a` is just path of 1 file you don't need `map_df` for that. `fread(filename_a, sep=",", skip=1)` should be enough.

Comment: filename_a is a list of file names.

Comment: So you mean you have list of file names in `filename_a` as well as list of filenames in `filename_b` ? Which will file from `filename_b` will you read when one of the file from `filename_a` fails to read?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `tryCatch` as follows :

```
library(data.table)

data <- tryCatch(fread(filename_a, sep=",", skip=1), 
         error = function(e) return(fread(filename_b, sep=",", skip=1)))
```